# "Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace" when running capybara with webkit

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

When I run with `:focus => true` like this it works fine:

```
it "should send by email to new user", :js => true, :focus => true do
  ...
end
```

However, when I remove the `:focus => true` and run the full test suite I get this error on that test.

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
```

It seems to be something with the `:js => true` maybe since this is the first test where I started using that. capybara-webkit prints a bunch of warnings to the screen when I run the one test by itself.

But when I run the full suite I see no warnings from webkit, so it's almost like it's not being loaded.

Any ideas?  Thanks I really appreciate it!

In case you are curious here is the relevant part of my gemfile:

```
group :test do                       
  gem "rspec-rails",                 '2.10.1'
  gem "ruby_gntp",                   '0.3.4'
  gem 'capybara',                    '1.1.2'
  gem 'capybara-webkit',             '0.11.0'  # requires "brew install qt"
  gem 'guard-rspec',                 '0.6.0'
  gem 'mocha',                       '0.10.0'
  gem 'spork',                       '~> 1.0rc'
  gem 'guard-spork',                 '0.5.2'
  gem 'launchy',                     '2.0.5'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, well I seemed to solve it but I don't think it had anything to do with capybara or webkit.  It seemed to be an issue in eventmachine I was having.  I basically took out any calls to EventMachine's `send_data` while in Rails.env.test.  I'm still not sure why it wasn't able to get a backtrace though.